# Find stored procedure dependencies on MySql

Tags: mysql, dependencies

I'm working on a 8.0.15 Mysql on which I have several stored procedures.
The "master" call the others, and every procedure may (or may not) call other procedures themselves

My goal is to have a "tree" of the procedures, to document the order on which they are called.

Any ideas on how to do so? I was thinking to query information_schema.`ROUTINES` tables, extract only the various Call with some regex to have only the "bone" of my procedures, something like:

```
MAIN_PROCEDURE
  CALL PCD2();
  CALL PCD3();
END;

PCD2
  CALL PCD4();
END;
```

then, recursively do it in order to know that PCD4 is called inside PCD2.

I'm stuck on the first part, then the recursive query should be quite easy

Any help? Of course any other method is fine!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

would like to know if there is an automatic way to deal with unbalanced data. Let's say it is a binary classification problem and I want to use cross-validation, for example kfolds.
Do you know if there is any cross-validation technique that does not only randomly shuffle the data, but also tries to "balance" the labels in the train set so it is 50%-50%?
That would help to not get high accuracy scores, just because the model has higher changes to learn more points from a particular class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Put your database name in "MyDataBase".

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `dependencias`()
    NO SQL;

BLOCK1:BEGIN

```
DECLARE bas, c1 VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE fin int DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT  specific_name from information_schema.routines where routine_schema= bas;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin = TRUE;

SET  bas='MyDataBase';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dependencias;
CREATE  TABLE dependencias (a varchar(50), b varchar(50));
OPEN cur1;
rulo1: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO c1;
    IF fin THEN
        LEAVE rulo1;
    END IF;
    BLOCK2: BEGIN
        DECLARE can int; 
        DECLARE c2,cad varchar(50);
        DECLARE fin int DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT  specific_name from information_schema.routines where routine_schema= bas; 
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET fin = TRUE;
        OPEN cur2;
        rulo2: LOOP
        FETCH cur2 INTO  c2;
            IF fin THEN
                LEAVE rulo2;
            END IF;
            SET cad=CONCAT ('%',c2,'(%');
                SET can=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.routines WHERE Routine_Name = c1 AND routines.routine_definition LIKE cad AND Routine_Schema = bas);
            IF c1!=c2 AND can>0 THEN
                INSERT INTO `dependencias` values (c1,c2);
            END IF;  
        END LOOP rulo2;
        CLOSE cur2; 
    END BLOCK2; 
END LOOP rulo1;
CLOSE cur1;
```

END BLOCK1

---